# Can Echidna's ability be used during the turn in which it is purchased?

Tags: five-tribes

An interesting scenario came up while playing *Five Tribes* this weekend.

In *Five Tribes*, the djinn *Echidna*'s ability states

> Double the amount of GCs your Builders get this turn.

Tribe actions are done before tile actions, so if I dropped a blue meeple on a tile with other blue meeples and a scared place, I get the GCs from the blue meeples first. I then have the option to buy a djinn, and activate its ability immediately if desired (and if I have the necessary resources to do so).

All of the other djinn's abilities specifically call out when the ability may be used (e.g., "When placing a palm tree") or the actual timing is irrelevant within my turn (e.g., "Draw the top resource card").

However, *Echidna*'s ability refers to the GCs my Builders get **this turn**, which technically does include the Builders that acted before I had even bought the djinn - that was part of my turn. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Tile effect occurs AFTER Tribe effect.
So it's too late in this case: when you score your builders you don't have the Djinn yet.

From the rules (Section 2.5 Tile Action):

> Once your Meeples’ Tribe actions are over, perform the Action for the Tile your last Meeple ended on ...